# using sinon stub to test a method on an object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I want to test a function inside an object. The code, lets call it someFile.js, is structured as below.

```
import someService from 'a-location';

const val = someService.getVal();

const AnObject = {
  someMethod() {
   if(val) //dosomething
  }
}

export default AnObject;
```

In the test file, I have code as below

```
import someService from 'a-location';
import AnObject from 'someFile';

describe("description", function(){
  it('more description', function() {
    sinon.stub(someService, 'getVal').returns('my-val');
    AnObject.someMethod();
})
})
```

I was hoping to receive 'my-val' when someService.getVal() is called in the someFile.js but it isn't working as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [import()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) to import the `AnObject` from `someFile` dynamically **after stubbing**.

E.g.

`some-file.ts`:

```
import someService from './a-location';

const val = someService.getVal();

const AnObject = {
  someMethod() {
    console.log('val: ', val);
  },
};

export default AnObject;
```

`a-location.ts`:

```
const someService = {
  getVal() {
    return 'real val';
  },
};

export default someService;
```

`some-file.test.ts`:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import someService from './a-location';

describe('description', () => {
  it('more description', async () => {
    sinon.stub(someService, 'getVal').returns('my-val');
    const AnObject = (await import('./some-file')).default;
    AnObject.someMethod();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  description
val:  my-val
    ✓ more description


  1 passing (8ms)
```

As you can see, the `val` is `my-val` which is a stubbed value.